# Formatted SD card as internal storage on Tecno Pop 3 running Android 6.0 and migrated all data to the SD card, but they're both full

Tags: sd-card, insufficient-memory, adoptable-storage

Migrated all data in my Tecno Pop 3 phone, but it happened like I copied them to the SD because internal storage wasn't freed.